# More concise way of chaining undefined keys

Tags: typescript

typescript Version 3.9.5
I have a very deeply nested schedule object:

```js
interface ISchedule{
  //an array of start and end times by day
  [year:number]:{
    [month:number]:{
      [day:number]:{
        start:string, 
        end:string
      }[] | null
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to go through each day in a given month and check if there are any times available. So far what I have is this:

```js
filterDay(year:number, month:number, day:number):boolean{
    //checks if a day is available in the schedule
    return this.schedule[year] ? this.schedule[year][month] ? this.schedule[year][month][day]?.length > 0 ? true  : false : false : false;
  }
```

is there a better when to chain each key if its null like `this.schedule[year]?[month]?[day]?.length`?

Comment: `this.schedule[year]?.[month]?.[day]?.length`

Comment: You're already using tne optional chaining operator (but only for the `.length`). Haven't you tested if it will also work for the other properties?